# How to close one set of Tab identified in Chromium through Command line

Tags: chromium

How to close one set of Tab identified in Chromium thru Command line;

As we can see that a set of tabs are represented thru a PID (process ID). I would like to know how to close the tabs from command line.

We know the process ID,

Comment: I am confused. Is this a question?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to close the tab. Kill -9 PID doesn't do it. It crashes the tab not closes it.

Answer (score 1):

The "tab" is more than just the "physical tab" you see in the window. What you killed was the process driving that "tab" (rendering, resource management, etc), thus "crashing" it, but not actually signalling to chrome to close it. I don't think you can actually close the tab in that manner, unless Chrome supports some kind of external signal for closing tabs (which Chrome would handle itself in a cleaner manner than "killing" the tab).

Comment: Also, a single "render process" can wind up managing multiple unrelated tabs - killing it will crash all the tabs at once. You can see which tabs are grouped together using Chrome menu > Tools > Task Manager.